# adjust distance between geom_text and bars with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot that present correlation values, and I am representing a significant correlation with a star on each bar. However, I cannot seem to increase the distance between the star and the bar, as the bars go both ways in the plot (some values are negative, other positive). I would like to know how to increase the distance of the text the same amount, just in different directions. 
`Nudge_x` and `nudge_y` will only change all the points in one direction in the plot. Additionally, the text labels do not seem to be centered on each bar.

Example:

```
df <- structure(list(ref2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), estimate = c(-0.220522748118839, 
-0.179731936253906, 0.0400276364582935, -0.568250677328796, 0.189980289483266
), sign = c("*", "*", NA, "*", "*")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(ref2, estimate)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = sign),
            size = 10) +
  coord_flip()
```

This result in the following plot:

[image]

What I want to end up with:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vjust` and `hjust` should help here:

```
ggplot(df, aes(ref2, estimate)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = sign), 
            hjust = ifelse(df$estimate < 0, 1.5, -0.5),
            vjust = 0.75,
            size = 10) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new dataframe that takes the sign of each row of df$estimate and multiply it by an offsetFactor. This column/array can then essentially act as a new offsetted y-axis for your geom_text to give you the effect you want.

```
df2 <- data.frame(df$estimate) %>% mutate(newEstimate = df$estimate + sign(df$estimate)*0.03)

ggplot(df, aes(ref2, estimate)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(y = df2[,2], label = sign), size = 10) +
  coord_flip()
```